# Applications discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A racketeer is allowed to bring no more than 3 of the 7 lawyers representing him to a Senate hearing. How many choices does he have?

This is what I have done but the correct answer is 64. I'm not sure how to get that answer.

$ C(7,3)=\frac{7!}{3!4!}=35$

Comment: I assume he has $7$ lawyers in total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No more than 3" means he doesn't have to bring *exactly* 3 of his 7 lawyers: he can also bring only 0, 1 or 2 of them:. This gives you
\begin{align}
\text{number} &= \binom{7}{0} + \binom{7}{1} + \binom{7}{2} + \binom{7}{3}\\
&= 1 + 7 + 21 + 35\\
& = 64
\end{align}